# How to create the following table?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I was unable to create the following table
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{c |c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{Figure Here} \\ \cline{2-3}
 & First entry & Second entry    \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{First door} & $\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\end{aligned}$  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Second door} &  $\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\end{aligned}$  \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Ways} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, you use the `aligned` environment, but don't have whatever to align, and the texts of the code doesn't correspond to the image…

Comment: @Bernard: I used the `aligned` environment because I repeatedly get an error when I write `$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$` inside the table.

Comment: @marya - You most definitely shouldn't use `$$...$$` inside a `tabular` environment. Write `$\displaystyle ... $` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to recommend that you give the table a much more open look, mainly by (a) omitting all vertical lines and (b) using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. Your readers will certainly appreciate it -- and they will likely show their appreciation by actually taking the time to read and understance the table's contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{ c@{}}{Figure Triangle Here} \\ 
 \cmidrule(l){2-3}
 & First entry & Second entry    \\ 
 \midrule
First door & $\dfrac{\beta\mathstrut}{\alpha}$ & $\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}$  \\ 
\addlinespace
Second door &  $\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha\mathstrut}$ & $\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}$  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Ways} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: Your objective may be achieved by (a) loading the `caption` package and (b) replacing

```
 \multicolumn{2}{ c@{}}{Figure Triangle Here}
```

with

```
 \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{
 \begin{minipage}{3.5cm}
 \centering 
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{triangle.jpg}
 \captionof*{figure}{Figure: Triangle}
 \end{minipage}}
```

Comment: I am unable to make a caption of the figure. I added  `\multicolumn{2}{c @{}}{\includegraphics[]{triangle.jpg}}` along with `graphicx` package.

Comment: @marya - I'm not sure I understand. First off, there's a `table` environment, not a `figure` environment. Second, the code already a `\caption` statement; did you try to add another one? Please clarify. Regarding the triangle: Did you replace the directive `\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Figure Triangle Here}` with `\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\includegraphics[width=<some width>]{triangle.jpg}}`?

Comment: Yes, I did but I want to add a caption for the figure like in the diagram shown in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This code works fine without `aligned`. I suggest to use the `cellspace` package to give cells some padding (otherwise, the fractions touch the horizontal lines), and the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` – in my opinion text fractions look petty in this context. Last remark: since version 3.9 of babel, it is recommended the language option be loaded with the document class, so language-dependent packages be aware of the main language in the document.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{Sc|}}
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{Sc| }{Figure Here} \\ %
 \cline{2-3}
 & First entry & Second entry \\ %
 \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{First door} & $ \mfrac{\beta}{\alpha}$ & $ \mfrac{\beta}{\alpha} $ \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Second door} & $ \frac{\beta}{\alpha} $ & $ \frac{\beta}{\alpha} $ \\ %
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Ways}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]